# How to determine if lists have at least one same element

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, intersection, set-intersection

Product table contains tags columns:

```
create table product(
  product char(20) primary key,
  tag1 char(100),
  tag2 char(100) )
```

tag columns contain tags separated by semicolon like

```
AB;AC;AD
RXX;AC;XAD
RP12;X455;R444;AXD
```

How to find all rows where tag1 and tag2 columns contain at least one same tag ?

For example row

```
tag1        tag2
AB;AC;AD    RXX;ZAC;XAD;AC
```

should be in result since both columns contain AC

Row

```
tag1        tag2
AB;XAC;AD    RXX;ZAC;XAD;AC
```

Should not be in result since all tags are different.

Using  PostgreSQL 13.2

Comment: [Dont' use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29). For this specific situation, an array (`text[]`) or `jsonb` column would be better rather than the dreaded delimited strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `&&`  operator to check if there are common elements in the columns. To do this, you must first convert the string to an array using the `string_to_array`

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  (string_to_array(tag1,';')::text[]) && (string_to_array(tag2,';')::text[])
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=39a774496749fd86c6b9e8cecc8606cb)